# Re-initializing local variable using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a `JUnit` for a method and I need to re-initialize `ServiceContext` in order to get a full branch coverage for that line. I am not sure how to access `ServiceContext object`because every time ctx is `null` it adds message into it. Is there any way to access this explicitly so that I tune it the way I want it or not?

Method under test:

```
public AgencyResponse getAgency(@QueryParam(ServiceConstants.AGENCY_CODE) String agencyCode,
        @QueryParam(ServiceConstants.EFFECTIVE_DATE) long effectiveDate) throws WebServiceException {
    ServiceContext ctx = getServiceContext();
    getBaseComponent().logMethodStartDebug(ctx, CLASS_NAME, "getAgency()" ); 

    AgencyResponse response = new AgencyResponse();

    try {
        if( effectiveDate < 1 ) {           
            effectiveDate = new Date().getTime();
        }

        ctx.addParameter( ServiceConstants.AGENCY_CODE, agencyCode );
        ctx.addParameter( ServiceConstants.EFFECTIVE_DATE, DateUtil.convertToDate( effectiveDate, false ) );

        validateRequest( ctx, response );

        IProviderChain providerChain = (IProviderChain)AppContext.getBean( ServiceConstants.AGENCY_PROVIDER_CHAIN );
        response = (AgencyResponse)providerChain.retrieveData( ctx );

        if( response == null ) { //precaution
            response = new AgencyResponse();
        }

        if( response.getAgency() == null ) {
            if(ctx.getMessages()==null || ctx.getMessages().isEmpty()){
                ctx.addMessage( ErrorMessageUtil.generateMessage( getBaseComponent().getMessageFactory(), ErrorCodeConstants.STATUS_2000 ) );
            }
        }

        return (AgencyResponse)finalizeResponse( response, ctx );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what  do you want to tune for example ?

Comment: org.omg.IOP.ServiceContext ?

Comment: can't you just mock the getServiceContext() method so that it returns null in your 2nd test ?

Comment: if ctx.getMessages() is null then ctx add messages into it. Fof that particular line I want to get a 100% branch coverage. I can initialize ctx to whatever I want using Reflection but when I debug the code and reaches to this method ctx becomes null and on the next line messages are added into it. I don't want to use any Mocking framework, just wanted to know if I can achieve such a thing using core java.